# Chrome Mobile 108: touchcancel not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

How can I get a handler to run when the touch is canceled? (For example, so I can unhighlight a button [when CSS doesn't do it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843213/chrome-mobile-javascript-events-corresponding-to-css-active-state-changes#)). In older Chrome Mobile browsers, I can catch `touchcancel` events. However, in Chrome Mobile 108 (from 2022), there is no `touchcancel`:

[image]

What event is generated when the touch (and subsequent `click` event) is canceled due to timeout? (Note: moving the touch off the element is a [separate question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748476/) with a [decent polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5748761/5896591).)

I am using the following script to catch events:

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<style>
html, body, pre {
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  margin: 0; user-select: none;
}
pre {margin: 10px; overflow-y:auto}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="ELEM"></pre>

<script>

ELEM = document.getElementById("ELEM")
ELEM.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

function Print(s)
{
  let t = (new Date() / 1000 % 60).toFixed(2).padStart(5,0);
  ELEM.firstChild.nodeValue += `${t}: ${s}\n`;
  ELEM.scrollTop = ELEM.scrollHeight;
}

Print("Hello, world!");
EVENTS = ["mouseup", "mousedown", "touchstart", "touchend", "click", "touchcancel", "mouseenter", "mouseout", "focusin"];
for (let e of EVENTS)
  document.body.addEventListener(e, () => {Print(e)});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really really hoping there's a way to fix this without rewriting `click`. However, otherwise (or in the meantime) here is a possible approach:

- The application ignores the built-in `click` event (as we can't catch its timeout).
- On `touchstart`, start a timeout (what time value should I use?).

  - If the timeout fires, then generate a normal `touchcancel` event.
- On `touchend`, if the timeout has not fired, then  generate a click event to the application and clear the timeout.

Here is an example of a `Better_Click()` function that uses the above method to launch `touchcancel` and `better-click` events to the application:

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<style>
html, body, pre {
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  margin: 0; user-select: none;
}
pre {margin: 10px; overflow-y:auto}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="ELEM"></pre>

<script>

ELEM = document.getElementById("ELEM")
ELEM.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

function Print(s)
{
  let t = (new Date() / 1000 % 60).toFixed(2).padStart(5,0);
  ELEM.firstChild.nodeValue += `${t}: ${s}\n`;
  ELEM.scrollTop = ELEM.scrollHeight;
}

function Better_Click(el)
{
  let to;
  function timeout()
  {
    to = undefined;
    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("touchcancel", {}));
  }
  el.addEventListener('touchstart', () => to = setTimeout(timeout, 700));
  el.addEventListener('touchend',   () => {
    if (to === undefined)
      return;
    clearTimeout(to);
    to = undefined;
    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("better-click", {}));
  });
}
Better_Click(document.body);


Print("Hello, world!");
EVENTS = ["mouseup", "mousedown", "touchstart", "touchend", "touchcancel", "mouseenter", "mouseout", "better-click"];
for (let e of EVENTS)
  document.body.addEventListener(e, () => Print(e));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```